# React Router: Route в дочернем компоненте не срабатывает

Tags: reactjs, react-router

В главном компоненте я использую switch

```
function Router(props) {

    return (<main>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/prices/'
                   render={(props) => <PricesPage {...props} />}
            />
            <Route path="/prices/add/"
                   render={(props) => <PriceGroupAddFormConnected {...props}/>}
            />
        </Switch>
    </main>) 
}
```

В одном из дочерних компонентов PricesPage объявляю Route

PricesPage:

```
function PricesPage(props) {

    return (<Child/>) 
}
```

Child:

```
function Child(props) {

    return (
            <><Route exact path="/prices/dialog" component={Dialog}/>
            <Child1/></>)
        )

}
```

А в child1 располагается Link

Child1:

```
function Child1(props) {

    return (
            <Link to="/prices/dialog"/>)
        )

}
```

Ожидаю: когда я кликаю в child1 на ссылку, открывается модальное окно

Сейчас: ссылка меняется, однако модальное окно не открывается. Если располгать роут в главном компоненте, то открывается, но при этом закономерно не сохраняются остальные компоненты под диалоговым окном, которые необходимо продолжать отображать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вышестоящем роуте у вас стоит `exact`, а значит по ссылке `/prices/dialog` этот роут не срабатывает и дочерний компонент не вызывается, следовательно не работает и роут в дочернем компоненте. Уберите `exact` и поменяйте местами роуты, чтобы не было ложных срабатываний

```
function Router(props) {

    return (<main>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/prices/add/"
                   render={(props) => <PriceGroupAddFormConnected {...props}/>}
            />
            <Route path='/prices/'
                   render={(props) => <PricesPage {...props} />}
            />
        </Switch>
    </main>) 
}
```